# Create a txt file asp.net application access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, click, user-tracking

We tried creating a txt file using this code

```
using (StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/data.txt"), true))
     {
      _testData.WriteLine(" asd"); // Write the file.
     }
```

But we get the message **Access to the path 'L:...\data.txt' is denied**

Can this be done with Anonymous disabled and NETWORK SERVICE out of the users group in security of the folder?

**Upd**: We have a web application and we want to track the number of clicks on a certain button to get statistics for a month of its usage by each user, we cant use any database (not even access).

Is the best approach to create a txt file?

Comment: usually the APP_DATA folder has all the permissions required. Try to write your file there.

Comment: Is the folder that you are trying to put the file in read only?  You can check in the folder properties.

Comment: Depends which user the application is running under. If it's a .net 4.0+ website, it's most likely a user called 'IIS APPPOOL\<app-pool-name>'. As Steve suggested, try writing to "~/App_Data/data.txt" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look to the IIS trust level.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754779.aspx

Depending on your configuration (above and medium included), you will not be able to write a file outside the application directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for appending data to a textfile as a log.

```
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.AppendText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.txt")))
        {
            stream.WriteLine("testing..");
            stream.Flush();
        }
```

Put that in your Index() method on your controller and it will append "testing.." for each visit. Enjoy :)